# Black Background Issue with GD Library while adding watermark

Tags: php, image, joomla, gd, watermark

I am facing issues with adding watermark to images using GD Library, the same code works fine on my local Ubuntu Server which has PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 with GD version 2.0 but produces a black background to the image after the ending of the watermark image, my website is hosted on hostgator and i have also upgraded the server to use PHP Version 5.4.20 with GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible) but still the same issue.

The following is the code that works for the local server but produces the black image on the server

```
imagecreatefromjpeg($img);

$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_src);
imagealphablending($watermark, true);
//imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
$black = imagecolorallocate($watermark, 0, 0, 0); 

imagecolortransparent($watermark, $black);

imagecopy($img, $watermark, $final_x, $final_y, 0, 0, $W, $H);

imagedestroy($img);

imagejpeg($img);
```

Also i have tried making many changes to the code for the server to work like removing the code for the black variable adding imagesaveaplha etc but still no luck.

The variables names may differ for the functions because the process uses multiple function to accomplish the task the but the sequence is the same the i have written above. Also the code works fine if i run it separately but when i am using it with my joomla component it has the black background issue

Comment: $sourceImage and $renderImage are not defined in your source; please clarify: is the watermark image a transparent png? if this is the case - or you can make it so - you can skip imagecolortransparent; also you need to uncomment imageSaveAlpha()

Comment: they are defined but are coming from a different function, the error lies with the imagecopy function only, i have tried removing the imageSaveAplha() but did'nt help, thanx

Comment: yes but you're using $img, $sourceImage and $renderImage it doesn't matter where they come from, you're watermarking one and saving the other.  Also, are the files local? otherwise you better download them ahead, remote_file_include doesn't work properly with GD

Comment: yes they are local, i have changed the variable name for a better understanding, which might help now, & finally i am saving the $img resource, thankx.